Multiplicative inverse to the Dirac delta in physics
In this paper, The binding of cosmological structures by massless topological defects, on page 2 (and 4), the author Richard Lieu defines "a length $s \to 0$ with the property that $s\delta(R - r) = 1$ at $r = R$".
I am puzzled with this definition. Note I come from a mathematical point of view, but I am equally puzzled on how one would make sense of such a thing either mathematically or physically. The LHS is a distribution, but I cannot make sense of the RHS as a distribution. Of course, the constant 1 is a distribution
$$\varphi \mapsto \displaystyle\int \varphi \, \mathrm dx$$
but there is no feasible way to interpret the LHS in this way.
If $s$ is a constant, then
$$\langle s \delta_{R = r}, \, \varphi \rangle = s\langle \delta_R,  \, \varphi \rangle = s \varphi(R).$$
But this can never equal to $\displaystyle\int \varphi \, \mathrm dx$ for all $\varphi$. So $s$ cannot be a constant.
What if $s$ is taken to be a distribution, then? In general, multiplying distributions is of scrupulous nature. Then we are looking for a multiplicative inverse of $\delta_0$, an infinitesimal version of Dirac delta. I have never seen this being done formally. You could try to define a distribution via a box extending horizontally instead of vertically, but then all test functions would map to zero.
If we try to solve what $s$ should be with a Fourier transform we get $\mathcal F\left(s\delta_R\right) = \mathcal F\left(1\right)$, which gives us
$$\hat s * e^{- i\omega R} = 2\pi \delta_0(\omega)$$
using the convention $\mathcal F\left(f\right)(\omega) = \displaystyle\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-j \omega t} \, \mathrm dt$.
Now, we need to solve for $\hat{s}$. However this is not clear how to find such an $\hat s$.
Convolutions are defined formally via
$$(u * v) * \varphi = u * (v * \varphi).$$
So we need a distribution $\hat s$ so that
$$\hat s * \left(e^{-i\omega R} * \varphi(\omega) \right) = 2\pi \varphi(0)$$
for all $\varphi$. It is not clear what this would be. This would only solve for $\hat{s}$, and that we then have to perform an inverse transform to get $s$.
Note that this purely a formal calculation, too.
And physically, I cannot conceive any reasonable interpretation either. A $\delta(t)$ can usually be thought as a limiting approximate identity, i.e. a normalized box or Gaussian that gets infinitely centered around the origin. A derivative of $\delta(t)$ also makes physical sense: $\delta'(t)$ is just something that goes from being 0 to be very positive just before the origin, to then be very negative just after the origin and then returns to 0.
A sloppy calculation shows
$$\begin{align*}\displaystyle \int \varphi(x) \delta'(x) \; \mathrm dx &= \displaystyle \int \left(\varphi(0) + \varphi'(0)x + \cdots \right) \delta'(x) \; \mathrm dx  \\ &\approx \displaystyle \int \left(\varphi(0) + \varphi'(0)x + \cdots \right)\frac{\delta(x+\varepsilon) - \delta(x -\varepsilon)}{2 \varepsilon} \; \mathrm dx \\ &= \displaystyle \int \varphi(0) \frac{\delta(x+\varepsilon) - \delta(x -\varepsilon)}{2 \varepsilon} \; \mathrm dx + \displaystyle \int \varphi'(0)x \frac{\delta(x+\varepsilon) - \delta(x -\varepsilon)}{2 \varepsilon} \; \mathrm dx  + \cdots \\ &= 0 + \varphi'(0) \frac{-2 \varepsilon}{2\varepsilon}  \to -\varphi'(0). \end{align*}$$
This agrees with the distributional formalism where $\langle \delta', \, \varphi \rangle = -\varphi'(0)$.
But a multiplicative inverse? No, that does not make sense.
What does the author mean?

For what it's worth, as someone with a physics/cosmology background and not a math background, if I was refereeing this paper I wouldn't have recommended it be published as is because I don't know what that means either. It did get published, but the published version doesn't clarify this point: https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/531/1/1630/7673084. Anyway as far as I'm aware this isn't a standard procedure in physics, and right before introducing this construction the author does say "At this point, we depart from the conventional approach."
